# IE8 local storage event fires in document not in window. Why this is different?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, local-storage

```
$(document).bind('storage', function (e) {
    if(!document.hasFocus() && localStorage.getItem("MapLoginStatus") == "false"){
         //// action
    }    
});

This works in IE8 not in chrome.

$(window).bind('storage', function (e) {
    if(!document.hasFocus() && localStorage.getItem("MapLoginStatus") == "false"){
        //// action
    }  
});

This works in Chrome not in IE8
```

How to identify, which one works? 
Is there any functions like localStorage.inside(window) - or something like that?

Thanks.

Comment: possibly because the localstorage API hadn't been standardised when IE8 was released? What results do you get for later IE versions? Do they follow IE8 or Chrome?

Comment: Seems like there is no javascript function available to find this. Have to write our own function. From IE8 alone uses in document.